# CakePhp i18n translation words order in .po files

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.5

Currently in a view I have this:

```
<span style="color: #2363a2;"><?php echo __('Accèdez à tous les %spronostics%s d\'%s', '<span style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">', '</span>', AppController::getSiteName()); ?></span>
```

In my .po file I have this:

```
msgid "Accèdez à tous les %spronostics%s d'%s"
msgstr "Reach all the %s %spicks%s"
```

The translation I get (from french - msgid - to english - msgstr -) is wrong.

The 1st %s value in msgstr should be the 3rd %s value in msgid.
I did some researches related to i18n for cakephp but I didn't find nothing related to my issue.

Do you know how to 'set the order' of the translated %s ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues in the past when passing the replacement arguments as multiple function arguments. Using an array tends to be more reliable:-

```
__(
    'Accèdez à tous les %spronostics%s d\'%s', 
    [
        '<span style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">', 
        '</span>', 
        AppController::getSiteName()
    ]
)
```

**Update:**

You need to specify the correct order in the translated string like this:-

```
msgid "Accèdez à tous les %spronostics%s d'%s"
msgstr "Reach all the %3$s %1$spicks%2$s"
```

Using `%3$s` tells Cake which of the parameters to use where the integer number represents the original ordering.

Comment: Ok but the issue is still the same. Instead of having `AppController::getSiteName()` in the 1st position (once translated to english), it's still on the 3rd one (like original transaction).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your original question. Looking at the code that handles the translation I'm not even sure you can easily fix the ordering of the replacements. :-/

Comment: I've just updated my answer with how to change the word sequence.

Comment: Thanks it works. Simply by editing the .po file according to your explanations. Editing the __() is not needed.